Blocking specific emails programmatically
I'm creating an app specific to an industry. To ensure that only industry persons are registering to use it I am requiring company emails to sign up. However, users have said that they then want to change their login email to their personal email address. With Firebase, how to I allow users to change their email address to their personal and then prevent them from creating a second account with their company email address? I don't have any code snippets to share because I literally don't know where to even begin with this.
I tried creating a collection of previously used emails but it doesn't work as a user needs to be authenticated and logged in to be able to get any documents from the database.

Updating a user's email is pretty trivial. You just need to call updateEmail(to:) on the user object from the authentication module.
Auth.auth().currentUser?.updateEmail(to: email) { error in
  // ...
}


I tried creating a collection of previously used emails but it doesn't work as a user needs to be authenticated and logged in to be able to get any documents from the database.

This is managed by your security rules and thus you can change this.
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /usedEmails {
      allow read: if true;
      allow write: if false;
    }
  }
}

But, it would be a pretty huge security problem if you publically allowed any user to get a list of all previously registered email addresses. There are a few solutions like anonymous authentication:
Auth.auth().signInAnonymously { authResult, error in
  // ...
}
guard let user = authResult?.user else { return }
let isAnonymous = user.isAnonymous  // true
let uid = user.uid

which you would then need to convert to a permanent account or link it against an existing account when you have the users email and password.
let credential = EmailAuthProvider.credential(withEmail: email, password: password)
annonymousUser.link(with: credential) { authResult, error in
  // ...
}

Another solution would be to confirm the user's email hasn't been used in a HTTP cloud function.
exports.emailAvailable = onCall((request) => {
  // check if email used
});

functions.httpsCallable("emailAvailable").call(["email": email]) { result, error in
  if let error = error as NSError? {
    // ...
  }
  // ...
}



How i would do is
To let users switch from their company email to their personal one in your app using Firebase
First, make sure users are logged in using Firebase authentication. Then, organize your Firestore database to hold user details like their current email, personal email, and company ID. When a user wants to update their email, double-check the new email to ensure it's not already used by another account. If it's unique, go ahead and update the user's info in Firestore. Also, during registration, make sure each company email is used only once to stop users from creating multiple accounts with the same email. And don't forget to set up Firebase Security Rules to only allow logged-in users to access and change their own info.
like for example
now user comes logs in with his company account
he will change to his personal email save both in the db so that you can tell that the user already exists na

Super good answer from @ColdLogic and follow their link on how to change email within the app.
There's probably a more direct path to handle events after the user registers with their company email and then changes it; use server level functions e.g. Cloud Functions.
In particular blocking Cloud Functions which executes custom code that modifies the result of a user registering to your app. For example; preventing a user for registering if they don't meet certain criteria.
In fact, blocking Cloud Functions can execute before the user is even created
import {
  beforeUserCreated,
} from "firebase-functions/v2/identity";

export const beforecreated = beforeUserCreated((event) => {
  // See if the user already auth'd with their company email
  return;
});

There are more in-depth examples at that link that will get you going.
This prevents a user from registering at all if their email is not from a specific domain
export const beforecreated = beforeUserCreated((event) => {
  const user = event.data;
  // Only allow emails containing a specific domain
  if (!user?.email?.includes('@mycompany.com')) {
    throw new HttpsError('invalid-argument', "Unauthorized email");
  }
});

